# Can I enter and exit the UK with 6 months 'leave to enter'?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

Is it possible to enter and exit the UK during my 'Leave to Enter' for 6 months visitor stamp. I will have been travelling for five months since the stamp and I am hoping to re-enter the country for a week before catching a flight back to New Zealand. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That leave to enter is irrelevant now. You will get a new leave to enter with another period, usually 6 months, when/if they land you in.

Comment: Unless they don't.

Comment: But if the OP has been traveling most of the time _outside the UK_ before applying for a new leave to enter, it doesn't sound particularly risky to apply for a new one.